# How do I make text in input go into paragraph on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, input

I am trying to make this website about time management for a project at school. I am trying to create a input (text box) that when the button "add task" is click it is placed (the text inside of it) in a paragraph or p2 and then the input is moved down.

This I think is the problematic section:
Sorry I have posted all the html, css, and Javascript in the html section  of the code snippet
Please I really need help

```html
<html>
    
 <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
     
    </style>
<header>
<title>ManageMe</title>
</header>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class= "title"> ManageMe </h1>
    <font face = "Times New Roman" size = "7">Next 7 Day Outlook</font><br />
    <div> 
        <h2> Today <span class= "june13">June 13</span></h2> 
        <div class="line1">
            <div> <br>
                <div id= "bonus">
                    <p id= "p1"> </p>
                </div>
  <input id= "first" type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter Task Here">
  <br>  
                <div>
                <button class="button" onclick ="addtask()"> Add Task </button>
                    
                 <div id="div">
 <button onclick ="appendRow()" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
 </div>
                    <div>
                        <p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>

                    </div>
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
             
 .june13 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line1 {
    
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
    
.button {
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  height: 25px;
    width: 70px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41
    }

    .button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

             input {
              
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 
             }
             
         
    
    
             
    </style>

</div>
    
    <script>
        
        
     function addtask() {
        
       var 1 = document.getElementById("first").value;
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = var 1;
        
         
         {
        
        
     function generateRow() {
   var d = document.getEleme    ntById('div');
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='food'>";
}
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is the problematic part

function addtask() {

```
   var 1 = document.getElementById("first").value;
     document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = var 1;


     {
```

[This image is what it looks like. As you can see the text box is where you put in the task you want or other input and then when you click the green button it will place it will place it above the current input box as a p2 and then the user is able to add another task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re8vz.png)

I know there is a lot of extra code however, I hope you get the basic idea

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Soo4K.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't name a variable as a number. You'd need to name it something else - also note you shouldn't have the `var` when you're using the variable.

```
var val = document.getElementById("first").value;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = val;
```

Comment: Thank you but I want it to (when the button "add task" is clicked) put it in the p2 and then make a new input below it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
Obviously you can't add rows because that function isn't created yet
As an advice I suggest you to use placeholder in your input instead of value.

```html
<html>
    
 <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
     
    </style>
<header>
<title>ManageMe</title>
</header>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class= "title"> ManageMe </h1>
    <font face = "Times New Roman" size = "7">Next 7 Day Outlook</font><br />
    <div> 
        <h2> Today <span class= "june13">June 13</span></h2> 
        <div class="line1">
            <div> <br>
                <div id= "bonus">
                    <p id= "p1"> </p>
                </div>
  <input id= "first" type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter Task Here">
  <br>  
                <div>
                <button class="button" onclick ="addtask()"> Add Task </button>
                    
                 <div id="div">
 <button onclick ="appendRow()" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
 </div>
                    <div>
                        <p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>

                    </div>
                    
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
         <style>
     
.title {
    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #b72121;
    
}
             
 .june13 {
     
     
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #989da5;   
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 } 
             
.line1 {
    
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
             }   
    
.button {
  
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  height: 25px;
    width: 70px;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41
    }

    .button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

             input {
              
                 margin-bottom: 10px;
                 
             }
             
         
    
    
             
    </style>

</div>
    
    <script>
        
        
     function addtask() {
        
       var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
       document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = first;
        
      
         }
        
        
     function generateRow() {
   var d = document.getElementById('div');
d.innerHTML+="<p><input type='text' name='food'>";
}
       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```